# Different amount of posts on homepage than paged pages

Tags: posts, query-posts, pagination

I've done some searches here and on Google but everything I'm finding isn't working correctly. I was hoping to post my code here and get help with where I'm going wrong.

On the index page of my site, I have one "featured" post that has a different layout than the rest of the posts. When you click to the next page, that featured post goes away and leaves me with an uneven count of posts and I need an even post count. Here's the code I found and have tried implementing with no joy.

I'm using the following query (everything else is the same at the count code and below):

```
<?php
  $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  query_posts("paged=$page&posts_per_page=10"); 
?>
```

This is the code I want to be able to use:

```
<?php
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$page_num = $paged;
    if ($pagenum='') $pagenum = 1;
    if ($pagenum > 1) { $post_num = 10 } else { $post_num = 9 }
query_posts('showposts='.$post_num.'&paged='.$page_num); `
?>
```

This would be the same for the rest of the page:

```
<?php $count = 1; ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if ((!is_paged()) && ($count == 1 )){  ?>

 // FEATURED HTML HERE

<?php } else {  ?>

 // REGULAR HTML HERE

<?php } $count++; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

// PAGINATION HERE
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `pre_get_posts` filter. You can exclude the homepage with `! is_front_page` or `! is_home` depending on your configuration.

```
/**
 * Changes the number of posts per page if not is_home
 *
 * @author  SFNdesign, Curtis McHale
 */
function wptt_change_posts_on_page( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '10' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wptt_change_posts_on_page' );
```

As I said, you may need to use `! is_front_page` depending on how your theme is set up. Here is a good blog post explaining more on those conditionals.

http://wpthemetutorial.com/2011/12/12/clearing-up-confusion-about-is_home-and-is_front_page/

Oh and never use `query_posts`, evar.
https://developer.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/querying-posts-without-query_posts/

Comment: +1 for `pre_get_posts`, but you'll still need to account for `paged`, since `is_home()` still returns `TRUE` on `paged` pages.

Comment: Thanks, I've discovered that neither yours or Johannes options work. Either wreck pagination. I'll have to come up with some other solution.

Answer (score 2):

The logic you came up with in the second snippet makes sense. Nonetheless, there are a couple of things wrong with your code.

For one, the `$pagenum` variable is redundant and you do not need it. For another, you assign the return value of `get_query_var()` to `$page` and then in the following lines use `$paged` - you want that to be the same. The following should do:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$post_num = ($paged > 1) ? 10 : 9;
// query for posts
```

Further, in the markup snippet (the 3rd one of your question), `$count` is not needed, you can simply use `$paged` as well. As an aside and for the sake of completeness, I would not employ so many php opening and closing tags, but that is a matter of taste and will not influence the functionality of your code.

One more: Unless this is your main loop, you should use the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class instead of `query_posts`. And if it is, the usage of `query_posts` is not as wrong, but it still would be recommendable you'd check out the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter instead.

Comment: This comes close to working correctly but when I page, it drops one post from the list on each page.